# Get PeasyCam to follow a sphere shape as it orbits another sphere in Processing

Tags: java, 3d, camera, processing

Sorry for all the code, but basically I am trying to set up a camera to follow a planet as it orbits around it's sun. How do I get the camera to follow the planet? The rotations in draw do not move the camera at all.

```
import peasy.*;
import peasy.org.apache.commons.math.*;
import peasy.org.apache.commons.math.geometry.*;
import peasy.test.*;


float sunRadius, planetRadius;
PImage mercury;
PImage the_sun;
PVector sunCenter;
PVector spoke;
Planet ourSun;
Planet ourPlanet;
float orbitSpeed = 0;
PeasyCam camera;



void setup()
{
  size(1000,700, P3D);

  sunRadius = 200;
  planetRadius = 50;

  mercury = loadImage("planet2.png");
  the_sun = loadImage("sun.jpg");

  sunCenter = new PVector(width/2, height/2, -500);
  spoke = new PVector(1,0,1);

  ourSun = new Planet(the_sun, sunRadius);
  ourPlanet = new Planet(mercury, planetRadius); 
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  ourSun.show(sunCenter);
  ourPlanet.orbit(sunCenter, spoke, orbitSpeed, 1000);

  pushMatrix();
      rotateY(orbitSpeed);
      camera = new PeasyCam(this, sunCenter.x, sunCenter.y, sunCenter.z, 4000);
      camera.setActive(false);
  popMatrix();

  orbitSpeed += 0.01;

}




class Planet {

  float sizeof;
  PShape planet;

    Planet(PImage img, float sizeof)
    {
        noStroke();
        noFill();
        this.sizeof = sizeof;
        planet = createShape(SPHERE, sizeof);
        planet.setTexture(img);
    }


    void show(PVector position)
    {
        pushMatrix();
        translate(position.x, position.y, position.z);
        shape(planet);
        popMatrix();
    }

    void orbit(PVector parent, PVector spoke, float speed, float distance)
    {
      pushMatrix();
          translate(parent.x, parent.y, parent.z);
          PVector traj = new PVector(parent.x-distance, 0, 0);
          PVector axis = traj.cross(spoke);
          rotate(speed, axis.x, axis.y, axis.z);
          translate(traj.x, traj.y, traj.z);
          shape(planet);
      popMatrix();

    }

}
```

I am having difficulty calculating the planet sphere's center point as it rotates and translates and also getting the peasycam to rotate about any axis successfully.

Comment: the textures(planet2.png and sun.jpg) are missing

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza appologies, the I don't know how to upload images here. Any image files will work to texture the spheres, or just use a fill in their place

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in MapleMath, there I had the moon rotating around earth and the two were orbiting the Sun. It is easy using Parametric equations . You want the camera to orbit Earth or to orbit the Sun . Your camera is located in a fixed position. Well beyond Earth.

I am just starting to learn Processing which already proves to have superior visuals. May I suggest that you use a Math program running Parametrics that will generate output tables of points
or vertices and cut and paste the table after beginShape. I have downloaded your code, and will work on it.
I am actually attempting to construct something very similar. I will be happy to share sometime soon.
vib
vburach@shaw.ca